# Can't set innerHTML for asp.net literal tag from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function CountChar(idTxtBox, idCharCount) {
        var maxLength = 500;
        var remChars = maxLength - document.getElementById(idTxtBox).value.length;

        document.getElementById(idCharCount).innerHTML = remChars + " of " + maxLength + " characters remaining";
    }
</script>
```

referenced by and referencing the following fields:

```
<tr>
    <td class="pageText2"><asp:Literal runat="server" id="litLastUpdateInfo"></asp:Literal></td>
    <td class="pageText2" style="text-align: right;"><asp:Literal runat="server" id="litCharCount"></asp:Literal></td>
</tr>

<tr><td colspan="2" class="pageText2Bold">Note: </td></tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><asp:TextBox ID="txtStickyNote" style="padding:3px;" runat="server" Width="100%" Text="" CssClass="pageText2" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" maxlength="500" /></td>
</tr>
```

I'm calling the CountChar function on a KeyUp event set in the code behind on page load:

```
txtStickyNote.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "CountChar('" & txtStickyNote.ClientID & "', '" & litCharCount.ClientID & "')")
```

When I'm typing in the text area, I want the character count to decrease, but I'm getting the following error:

```
document.getElementById(idCharCount).innerHTML = remChars + " of " + maxLength + " characters remaining";
Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference
```

Is it because it's an asp:literal tag? I can change the type no problem just need to get the text to update.

Thanks

Comment: You have to show us how `CountChar` is called, as the arguments probably aren't what you think they are.

Comment: Again, as I commented the previous time you asked this: you need to do a "view source" in the browser and see what ASP is doing to your "id" attributes.

Comment: Where are you binding or using the `CountChar` function? It's not in the snippet. And as @Pointy pointys out, it is probably the renaming of the ID by aspnet.

Comment: I added the attribute set from the code behind as an onKeyUp event for the textbox. I am passing the clientid that way so it should be using what's in the id field correctly. I had an issue before with the id attribute but when I set it in the code behind as I've included here, it's calling it correctly. Now, the issue is it just won't update the text in the literal tag.

Comment: So the issue was that I was trying to modify the innerHTML of a literal control. I switched it to a label and it's working now.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the generated HTML of the literal control

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that I was trying to modify the innerHTML of a literal control. I switched it to a label control and it is able to change the text as I type in the box.